# What is the name of this Aloe looking plant?

Tags: identification, plant-care

A friend of mine gave me this plant with no name or instructions of how to care for it. It looks like an Aloe plant to me but I'm not sure. Any suggestions on how to care for it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Hi there LOST!  It has been awhile.  You are right it is in the aloe agave family somewhere.  Your new family member needs some help for sure!  We'll be back...

Comment: Hi Stormy. Yes, it's been awhile. Glad to see your response. Ok I will be waiting...

Comment: That pot although it is plastic should work just fine for awhile.  Find out what kind of soil they used and the fertilizer.  I'd let him acclimate before any transplanting.  Fertilizer might just be the ticket but you gotta find out what they already have done, been doing.

Comment: Waaaa!  It was your Fiddle Leaf plant that didn't make it!  Bummer.  Did you get another one?

Comment: Yes, and its beautiful. I want to show you but I dont think I can add it to this post

Comment: Yeah, I get in trouble enough with my going off subject...I don't see any reason why you couldn't just add a picture to that original question with your poor other Fiddle Leaf!!?  I should get pinged...nice to see a GOOD ending!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[aloe vera plant](http://www.bing.com/cr?IG=64143FFF6DED49D2AD8FAE9AEC0B0ADA&CID=0A5271CFDE9A6F542D1B7B19DFC56EDC&rd=1&h=HvApLX0w0jjtXZPEaWQhCLVndwyI6gOc3emU4B9ch7E&v=1&r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feminiya.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F02%2Faloe-vera.jpg&p=DevEx,5038.1)  Sorry, this isn't more exact but it is aloe vera and quite old.  More light, I'd get a clay pot with drain holes, that is short and squat and the same diameter as the one it is in.  Could you ask your 'friend' when they last fertilized and with what?  Transplant into potting soil, no other additives.  There are potting soils for succulents/agave/cactus.  That would be fine to use.  But don't get a potting soil with gels/sponges for holding water!  These plants already have THAT solved by storing water in their leaves.

I'd use good ole Osmocote 14-14-14 at half the direction amount.  Find the brightest window but keep him out of direct sunlight.  Water only when the pot is light to lift.  Water shallowly, not deeply.  And this plant should start looking lots better!  Find out about the fertilizer before adding any fertilizer at all.

Those stakes are ugly...see if your new baby will stay upright without those stakes.  If not, find a stake that is unobtrusive such as a dove gray.  A bit of jute twine.

All you need to do then is IGNORE this plant!  Well, not ignore but babying will eventually kill it with love.  It should get greener with thicker leaves.  Clay pots are best I think for succulents and cactus as those pots breathe.

Are you a basketball expert?  Love all the memorabilia...how do you like New York anyway?

Comment: Great thanks for the advice. No I'm not a basketball expert, wish I was, lol. New York is wonderful, I was born and raised here. You should visit some time.

Comment: Wouldn't that be wonderful!  When I was a young, idiot, poor, hippie I traveled lots.  And now...hardly ever travel.  If I ever get the chance I will look you up...sounds like you'd know what is what and where in that big important city!  Especially great restaurants!!  I live in a podunk town with Mexican, Chinese and one pizza joint.  Have to travel an hour to be able to find Thai.  So we just learn to cook even better, lots of Thai.  I grow Thai basil and Thai peppers and lemon grass because there is NOWHERE to get decent ingredients!!  I am a country girl I guess but good food...yummmm.

Comment: Definitely look me up, I will show you everything. Oh boy, traveling an hour to find Thai, thats a bummer.

Comment: You have NO idea...grins!

Comment: Ive added the picture to my post "Brown spots on my fiddle fig"! Check it out

Comment: Shoot, I'll get one of my IT guys to help me find it.  How did you find it?  I keep getting zero answers.  I am not very patient with this stuff...errgghh. Looking forward to seeing your new plant!

Comment: Found it!  Absolutely beautiful.  Now I've seen your 'fiddle' and now you've got a 'cello' picture?  Are you a cellist??  Have you seen 2CELLOS?? The two young men from Croatia?  Classical music and instruments will never be the same!  If I could, I'd buy stock in Cellos!  What kid would chose any other instrument after watching these two amazing YOUNG men (they are like little kids still if you watch behind the scenes)...(giggling uncontrollably)...WOW.  They put Jimmy Hendrix to shame and I kid you not!  Great way to pull a theme throughout your home, grins!!